# Finding number of holidays between a given date range in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table named holiday_master in which 3 columns are there named from_date,to_date and duration.Now when user enters a date range,let daterange1 and daterange2,on the basis of holiday table,write a sql to find number of holidays.It will include both from_date and to_date.

For e.g
from_date   to_date     duration
2012/08/01  2012/08/03  3
2012/09/17  2012/09/24  8

User Enters: 2012/07/30  to 2012/08/02  (Number of holidays:2)
             2012/09/20  to 2012/09/29  (Number of holidays:5)

Comment: How do you want to handle overlapping holidays?

Answer (score 1):

The following query should work:

```
select coalesce(sum(datediff(day,
                     (case when h.from_date < t.fromdate then t.fromdate else h.from_date end),
                     (case when t.to_date > t.todate then t.todate else h.to_date end)
                   ), 0)
from (select @daterange1 as fromdate, @daterange2 as todate) const left outer join
     holidays h
     on h.from_date <= todate and h.to_date >= from_date;
```

Here is the logic.  First, I just put the constants into a constant table for convenience (limits the stress on the "@" key).  Then the query left joins the holidays table -- necessary in case there are no holidays in the period.

Then it does the logic where it compares overlapping time periods.  If the start of the holiday is before the time period, then make the start the beginning of the time period.  Same thing at the end.  Then, just add up all these time periods.

Depending on how the "to_date" is handled, you may need to add "1" into the period.  Is the "to_date" included as a holiday or not.  If it is included as a holiday, then the logic is:

```
select coalesce(sum(1+datediff(day,
                     (case when h.from_date < t.fromdate then t.fromdate else h.from_date end),
                     (case when t.to_date > t.todate then t.todate else h.to_date end)
                   ), 0)
```